# Bash script to recursively step through folders and delete files

Tags: linux, bash

Can anyone give me a bash script or one line command i can run on linux to recursively go through each folder from the current folder and delete all files or directories starting with '._'?

Comment: Just FYI: the `._` files are called AppleDouble files. On Mac systems, files have a data fork and a resource fork. The resource fork typically holds information such as icons, the file's spatial position in the folder (in Finder), and other metadata. The data fork (the actual file) contains the actual important data, so discarding the AppleDouble file shouldn't be problematic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change directory to the root directory you want (or change `.` to the directory) and execute:

```
find . -name "._*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

`xargs` allows you to pass several parameters to a single command, so it will be faster than using the `find -exec` syntax.  Also, you can run this once without the `|` to view the files it will delete, make sure it is safe.

Comment: This will be confused by filenames with spaces, which are common if you're dealing with files from a Mac environment.  Use the null-delimiter options to `find` and `xargs` (`find . -name "._*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf`) to avoid this problem.

Comment: Why not use the `-delete` option?

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -name '._*' -exec rm -Rf {} \;
```

Comment: Probably want to use `./` instead of `/`

Comment: There's a subtle difference between *the* root folder and *a* root folder.

Comment: Sorry, was a bit ambiguous, didn't mean THE root folder so ./ would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem a while ago (I assume you are trying to clean up a drive that was connected to a Mac which saves a lot of these files), so I wrote a simple python script which deletes these and other useless files; maybe it will be useful to you:

http://github.com/houbysoft/short/blob/master/tidy

Comment: Yep, u assumed correctly.  Supposedly its something apple are looking to fix to make macs more 'network friendly'.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path -name "._*" -exec rm -fr "{}" +;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the AppleDouble files, you could merge them with the corresponding files. You can use `dot_clean`.

> dot_clean -- Merge ._* files with corresponding native files.
>
> For each dir, dot_clean recursively merges all ._* files with their corresponding native files according to the rules specified with the given arguments. By default, if there is an attribute on the native file that is also present in the ._ file, the most recent attribute will be used.
>
> If no operands are given, a usage message is output. If more than one directory is given, directories are merged in the order in which they are specified.

Because dot_clean works recursively by default, use:

```
dot_clean <directory>
```

If you want to turn off the recursively merge, use `-f` for flat merge.

```
dot_clean -f <directory>
```

Answer (score -7):

`find . -name '.*' -delete`

A bit shorter and perform better in case of *extremely* long list of files.

Comment: Noooooooo! `.*` will delete all your dot files, and you need them!!! Don't do this people. It's a bad idea.